# BigQuery string-formatting to json

Tags: google-bigquery

Is the following a full list of all value types as they're passed to json in BigQuery? I've gotten this by trial and error but haven't been able to find this in the documentation:

```
select
    NULL as NullValue,
    FALSE as BoolValue,
    DATE '2014-01-01' as DateValue,
    INTERVAL 1 year as IntervalValue,
    DATETIME '2014-01-01 01:02:03' as DatetimeValue,
    TIMESTAMP '2014-01-01 01:02:03' as TimestampValue,
    "Hello" as StringValue,
    B"abc" as BytesValue,
    123 as IntegerValue,
    NUMERIC '3.14' as NumericValue,
    3.14 as FloatValue,
    TIME '12:30:00.45' as TimeValue,
    [1,2,3] as ArrayValue,
    STRUCT('Mark' as first, 'Thomas' as last) as StructValue,
    [STRUCT(1 as x, 2 as y), STRUCT(5 as x, 6 as y)] as ArrayStructValue,
    STRUCT(1 as x, [1,2,3] as y, ('a','b','c') as z) as StructNestedValue
```

```
{
  "NullValue": null,
  "BoolValue": "false", // why not just false without quotes?
  "DateValue": "2014-01-01",
  "IntervalValue": "1-0 0 0:0:0",
  "DatetimeValue": "2014-01-01T01:02:03",
  "TimestampValue": "2014-01-01T01:02:03Z",
  "StringValue": "Hello",
  "BytesValue": "YWJj",
  "IntegerValue": "123",
  "NumericValue": "3.14",
  "FloatValue": "3.14",
  "TimeValue": "12:30:00.450000",
  "ArrayValue": ["1", "2", "3"],
  "StructValue": {
    "first": "Mark",
    "last": "Thomas"
  },
  "ArrayStructValue": [
    {"x": "1", "y": "2"},
    {"x": "5", "y": "6"}
  ],
  "StructNestedValue": {
    "x": "1",
    "y": ["1", 2", "3"],
    "z": {"a": "a", b": "b", "c": "c"}
  }
}
```

Honestly, it seems to me that other than the `null` value and the array `[]` or struct `{}` container, everything is string-enclosed, which seems a bit odd.

Comment: That is how json works. :!  [ ] is an array datatype so it won't have double quotes. Same goes for {}

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), json is built on two structures:

> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
> realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
> list, or associative array.
>
> An ordered list of values. In most
> languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

The result of the SELECT query is in json format, wherein [] depicts an array datatype, {} depicts an object datatype and double quotes(" ") depicts a string value as in the query itself.